# WMI deviceID version win API device ID

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wmi

I was wondering how to convert a deviceID from WMI (e.g. select * from WIN32_PnPEntity where service='monitor') to a win API device ID (e.g calling EnumDisplayDevices).

WMI gives a device id such as "DISPLAY\DELA008\5&2F6B978F&0&UID16777488" whereas EnumDisplayDevices gives me a device id such as "MONITOR\DELA008{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001". How can I use the deviceID from WMI to call a win API function?